# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS crash when starting a guest on VMware 9.0.2

Tags: 12.04, kernel, suspend, vmware

Just recently moved to Ubuntu from MS platforms.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and using VMware 9.0.2 for various purposes.
A few days ago, my VMware workstation started to crash my system every time I start it after resume (I mean - Ubuntu is suspended and then resumed).
Not sure, but I think it started after one of the system updates i made a few day ago (I think there was a kernel update).

I use:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32bit), kernel 3.5.0-26-generic, VMware workstation 9.0.2, gnome-shell 3.6 (but it also crash when on Unity)

I tried re-install VMware, but no change.

Please help me to figure out what is causing it and how to resolve it.

EDIT: Since I can't yet attached a screenshot, here is a link to the image: http://postimg.org/image/mlddu6nzn/

Thanks!

Comment: "Crash" isn't' very descriptive. Can you update your question to explain exactly what happens?

Comment: @Jo-Erlend Schinstad:  by crash - I mean kernel panic with segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for Causing this problem is python 3 version. Ubuntu 12.10 has latest python 3 but VMware work station build requires python 2 for running. This is common Bug as also mentioned in ubuntu 12.10 Bugs. Wait till it be fixed.
Also, I suggest you to install 64bit version of Ubuntu.